# Should UX professional be involved in a fundraiser video (and to what extent)?

Tags: video

I am currently working on a fundraiser for my site (about 2 years old now).

I am going to create a video (with outside professional help), that will cover what the site is about (for new users), and what the fundraiser/promotion entails (price, duration, benefits, etc). Similar to a Kickstarter video.

The video will be integral in getting users to understand and support the fundraiser. It will have a link to the sign up page, and possibly instructions in the video (although the process is very simple, it might help just to show how simple the process is in the video).

I feel that the video content is very much integrated in the user experience. To what extent (if any), should the UX professional be involved with the video? I want the video professionals to have creative control, but I feel that leaving the UX professional out of the loop, would be a mistake.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clear answer: Yes, he should be if he's the one who has the most insight about your users. (He actually should be that guy, but you never know...) Like every interaction, watching a video as a user creates an experience.

At my work, we have some people started to make videos about our SaaS out of nowhere. I didn't even know about it. When I watch the videos now it's sometimes a real pita. Despite the lack of craftsmanship in video/audio, the content is sometimes completely useless ("click here to do this... click here to do that..." instead of "if you do this, our product will also do that and you don't even have to bother! yay!").

Your UX professional need to overview especially the *content* of the video. Does it explain your fundraising properly by addressing the users expectations? Especially in this case: Does it address their fears about giving away their money? Will it be in reliable hands? Too much "shiny super awesome promo style" might be the wrong way to go, instead you probably need to go for a "not so exciting, but solid and trustworthy" strategy. But this only your UX pro can (or should be able to) answer.

He also should brief the video guys about the creative strategy but leave the details to them as they (hopefully) know what they do. When it comes to approve the final cut, please don't let your very own oppinion judge. Instead ask yourself "have all the essential issues, our users have, been addressed in a way *they* understand?" If the answer is "yes" then the video is ok. "I don't approve the vid because I don't like the blue tone" or "I don't approve because xyz is not mentioned enough" is the best way to ruin a video project. (Says someone who used to work on vid projects for several years in a professional environment and even broadcast)

Comment: Thanks for the insight! I'll keep in mind not to let my personal opinion be a deciding factor in the final video.

Comment: And I have not yet hired a UX professional (although I'm strongly considering it). Just trying to see what tasks I would need a UX specialist for, before going and hiring someone.

Comment: @markstadt: If you're in doubt what a ux pro can/should/need to do and what all the other professions do, i recommend the following pdf. At my work, i use it to explain UxD and it actually works: http://www.methodbrain.com/posters/dsia-ux-design-practice-verticals.pdf (oh, and glad to see my answer was useful :)  )